# Laravel / PHP / MySQL - why is one column stored with a null value despite being provided a value via the Eloquent model?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

odd one here. I have a table with a number of columns (unusual, eh?) and am creating a row via an Eloquent model in Laravel (v9). Here is a snippet of the code

```
        while ($i <= $numrecs - 1) {

            // if the qty is non-zero then we want to store it

            if ($qtys[$i] != "") {
                
                $itemrec = MyItem::create([
                    'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                    'item_type_id' => $ids[$i],
                    'my_property_room_id' => 5,
                    'my_property_id' => session('g_my_property_id'),
                    'name' => $names[$i],
                    'qty' => $qtys[$i],
                    'comments' => $comments[$i],
                    'client_id' => 0,
                    'version' => 1,
                    'date_effective_from' => now(),
                    'status' => 'ACTIVE'
        
                ]);
```

See that column my_property_room_id? Well for some reason that is always being stored with a null value in MySQL irrespective of what value I pass through (whether in a variable or as in this last ditch attempt to ensure that a value is actually being passed - in this case 5).

I can send a query to MySQL such as this

```
update my_items set my_property_room_id = 5 where user_id=6;
```

and the column holds the value 5 directly afterwards - so it's not a problem with e.g. foreign key violations.

All the other column settings being sent into the Eloquent model are stored as expected.

Scratching my head as to the possible causes here - no error messages being send back to the browser and the expected number of records are being written - just with this one column remaining unfilled.

Anyone got any thoughts on what might be the cause?

Thanks in advance,
jeremy

Comment: Show the structure of the table.

Comment: Show your migration and/or the result of `show create table my_items` from MySQL. Do you have any mutators on the model?

Comment: Can you show your full `MyItem` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to add that property to the `$fillable` array of the Modelclass.

```php
// app/Models/MyItem.php

protected $fillable = ['my_property_room_id'];
```

Alternatively, you can just do:

```php
// app/Models/MyItem.php

protected $guarded = [];
```

**Note** The last option should only be used if you're not going to be mass assigning user input, so that you don't suffer injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks to all who responded - it was a classic developer mistake...originally called the column "property_room_id" - and the model was generated from this definition (reverse-engineered in fact from the table definition). I then somehow added the column "my_property_room_id" (should have been to replace "property_room_id") and didn't regenerate the model. So - good news, not found a fault with Eloquent :) - and to be clear, when I added the protected $fillable = ['my_property_room_id'] it worked like a dream...